# Create a tree from a list of strings containing paths

Tags: javascript, path, tree

**See edit below**

I wanted to try and create a tree from a list of paths and found this code on stackoverflow from another question and it seems to work fine but i would like to remove the empty children arrays instead of having them showing with zero items.

I tried counting  r[name].result length and only pushing it if it greater than zero but i just end up with no children on any of the nodes.

```
let paths = ["About.vue","Categories/Index.vue","Categories/Demo.vue","Categories/Flavors.vue","Categories/Types/Index.vue","Categories/Types/Other.vue"];

let result = [];
let level = {result};

paths.forEach(path => {
  path.split('/').reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
    if(!r[name]) {
      r[name] = {result: []};
      r.result.push({name, children: r[name].result})
    }
    
    return r[name];
  }, level)
})

console.log(result)
```

**EDIT**
I didnt want to ask directly for the purpose i am using it for but if it helps i am trying to create an array like this: (this is a copy paste of the config needed from ng-zorro cascader)

```
const options = [
  {
    value: 'zhejiang',
    label: 'Zhejiang',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'hangzhou',
        label: 'Hangzhou',
        children: [
          {
            value: 'xihu',
            label: 'West Lake',
            isLeaf: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: 'ningbo',
        label: 'Ningbo',
        isLeaf: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: 'jiangsu',
    label: 'Jiangsu',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'nanjing',
        label: 'Nanjing',
        children: [
          {
            value: 'zhonghuamen',
            label: 'Zhong Hua Men',
            isLeaf: true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

from an array of flat fields like this:

```
let paths = ["About.vue","Categories/Index.vue","Categories/Demo.vue","Categories/Flavors.vue","Categories/Types/Index.vue","Categories/Types/Other.vue"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a different approach.

This approach takes an object and not an array for reaching deeper levels and assigns an array only if the nested level is required.

```js
let paths = ["About.vue", "Categories/Index.vue", "Categories/Demo.vue", "Categories/Flavors.vue", "Categories/Types/Index.vue", "Categories/Types/Other.vue"],
    result = paths
        .reduce((parent, path) => {
            path.split('/').reduce((r, name, i, { length }) => {
                let temp = (r.children ??= []).find(q => q.name === name);
                if (!temp) r.children.push(temp = { name, ...(i + 1 === length && { isLeaf: true }) });
                return temp;
            }, parent);
            return parent;
        }, { children: [] })
        .children;

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... What does ??= do in JS. I dont think ive ever seen it before, on this line: let temp = (r.children ??= []).find(q => q.name === name);

Comment: it is a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

Comment: Thanks, it works great (after updating typescript to support the logical nullish).

Comment: Nina, is there anyway to modify this to add isLeaf:true when children is empty / missing? Thanks